# I keep getting this error when using the lowess() function

Tags: r, database

Hi I'm trying to use the `lowess()` in my graphic but i keep getting an error that I that I can't find an answer to.

This is what I have:

```
plot(y = nhanes2$BMPWTLBS, x = nhanes2$TCP, main="Relation between Serum cholosterol and weight converted to pounds from kilograms",
xlab="Serum cholesterol (mg/100ml)", ylab="Weight converted to pounds from kilograms")
abline(lm(nhanes2$BMPWTLBS~nhanes2$TCP), col="red")
lines(lowess(nhanes$TCP,nhanes2$BMPWTLBS), col="blue")
```

This is the error I get:

> Error in lowess(nhanes$TCP, nhanes2$BMPWTLBS) : 'delta' must be finite and > 0

Comment: Without a sample of your data that causes the error is it hard to say what happens in your particular case. A look at the documentation of `lowess` suggests that you may have `Inf` of other special values in `nhanes$TCP`. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't know how I can show you my data but both variables are numeric, I don't know if that helps

Comment: If you cannot reveal your data please include a minimal dataset which makes the problem reproducible [mre] this will help the SO community help you.

Comment: I can share but I don't know how to

Answer (score 1):

Does your dataset contain infinite values?.

In that case, try to remove infinite by replacing them by NA by using the following lines of code.

```
nhanes[!is.finite(TCP)] <- NA
nhanes[!is.finite(BMPWTLBS)] <- NA
```

Similar to this whichever column has infinite value, try to replace with NA.

You can have a view at your dataset by using

```
View(nhanes)
```

and look for **Inf**

Comment: My dataset doesn't contain infinite values, both of the variables in question are numeric